# How can I change the configuration for Failed Login Attempts for Member Authentication

Tags: silverstripe

If a member gets their login wrong a couple of times, they get logged out for 15mins. Is this configurable? To say 6 times locked for 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can see the configuration properties on the `Member` class:

```php
    /**
     * @config
     * @var Int Number of incorrect logins after which
     * the user is blocked from further attempts for the timespan
     * defined in {@link $lock_out_delay_mins}.
     */
    private static $lock_out_after_incorrect_logins = 10;

    /**
     * @config
     * @var integer Minutes of enforced lockout after incorrect password attempts.
     * Only applies if {@link $lock_out_after_incorrect_logins} greater than 0.
     */
    private static $lock_out_delay_mins = 15;
```

Modify them in your project's configuration files:

```yaml
# File: app/_config/security.yml
SilverStripe\Security\Member:
  lock_out_after_incorrect_logins: 6
  lock_out_delay_mins: 30
```

Ensure you flush your cache after changing YAML configuration files.